# ReferenceError: fn is not defined - ts-jest tests of Marklogic server side typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, marklogic, ts-jest

I'm using definitions of Marklogic types and functions from https://github.com/grtjn/marklogic-typescript-definitions and ts-jest to write tests for my modules. However I faced a problem with using predefined marklogic functions such as `fn.subsequence`. When I try to use it jest test it produces error:

> ReferenceError: fn is not defined

My IDE knows what's `fn.subsequence` and everything compiles just fine.
[image]

I've tried creating `fn` object and overriding `subsequence` method, but with no luck.

```
it('', ()=>{
    fn = {
       ... //here goes all the definitions of methods
    };
    fn.subsequence = (sourceSeq: ValueIterator<any>, startingLoc: number, length?: number)=>{return sourceSeq;};
```

I guess Marklogic is irrelevant here all of it is about ability to mock global (?) object and it's functions. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: I'd say MarkLogic is essential here, since you'd have to be running your code inside MarkLogic, otherwise fn functions are unknown. I don't think Jest allows you to run code inside MarkLogic. You might be better off using something like MarkLogic Unit Test: https://developer.marklogic.com/video/introduction-unit-test/

Comment: @grtjn thanks for suggestion, I've seen MarkLogic Unit Test before. However I wanted to try unit tests outside of MarkLogic to be able to mock returns and not be bound to MarkLogic instance in unit tests (which makes them something more than unit tests).